# setIsAccessibilityElement not working in Custom TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiaccessibility

I am using a Custom TableViewCell. I want to disable Accessibility for the cell and unchecked the accessibility in the Custom TableView Cell XIB. And even in the Implementation file, i am trying to set the setIsAccessibilityElement to NO.

**[self setIsAccessibilityElement:NO];**

and i have set the AccessibilityElement as No for the subviews inside the TableViewCell. But still i find that the accessibility is enabled when i run the application.

Can anyone please suggest any other alternative way to disable the Accessibility to a **Custom TableViewCell**?

Answer (score 1):

try self.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES;